# Color letters in JTextPane efficiently with kotlin coroutine

Tags: swing, kotlin-coroutines, jtextpane

I have a text of 10k characters. And i want to color each letter individually. (probably not what JTextPane was designed to do)

I noticed that the following method takes a long time:

```
 // The code snippet below is run via         
 // EventQueue.invokeLater { myRenderFrameFunction(text) }

 // Omissions

 text.forEachIndexed { index, character ->
    styledDocument.setCharacterAttributes(index, 1, colorings[character], false)
 }
```

I takesabout 27 ms to run

I'm not experienced with coroutines but I thought they could help me.

```
text.forEachIndexed { index, character ->
     coroutineScope {
         async {
             styledDocument.setCharacterAttributes(index, 1, colorings[character], false)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

If I run the above with either `runBlocking {}`  or `GlobalScope.launch {}` I do not get any performance boost. (But i do get wacky behavior if i do it with GlobalScope)

(Side question: I feel like my code overwhelms  `EventQueue.invokeLater {...})`, can i like slow down my frame generation to the ui's pace dynamically? somehow)

Why doesn't coroutines help in this instance? I feel like Im out of luck with this swing thing. Do you think making `setCharacterAttributes(...)` target spans of letters will have an impact for the strings with long stretches of the same letter?

Comment: I'd `launch` one single coroutine (in `Dispatchers.Main`), then run `text.forEachIndexed { ... }` inside that coroutine. Then to prevent taking up the main thread for too long, add `if (index % 1000 == 999) yield()`. I don't think it'll be any faster, after all you're calling `setCharacterAttributes` a whole bunch of times, but the UI would probably stay responsive.